# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, attributes, split

I have a script with these two functions:

```
# Getting content of each page
def GetContent(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content

# Extracting the sites
def CiteParser(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    print "---> site #: ",len(soup('cite'))
    result = []
    for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
        result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0])
    return result
```

When I run program I have the following error:

```
result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Output Sample:

```
URL: <URL That I use to search 'can be google, bing, etc'>
---> site #:  10
site1.com
.
.
.
site10.com

URL: <URL That I use to search 'can be google, bing, etc'>
File "python.py", line 49, in CiteParser
    result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Can you provide example input for the content parameter?

Comment: `cite.string` is returning you a `NoneType`

Comment: @cppcoder How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Make sure that `cite.string` has proper values in each iteration. Validate it before applying `split` function.

Comment: In order to provide answers, you need to tell us what is `cite` object and what does `cite.string` return.

Comment: cite is tags like `<cite></cite>` in content of pages. and it returns `site1.com till site10.com`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can happen, that the string has nothing inside, than it is "None" type, so what I can suppose is to check first if your string is not "None"

```
# Extracting the sites
def CiteParser(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    #print soup
    print "---> site #: ",len(soup('cite'))
    result = []
    for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
        if cite.string is not None:
            result.append(cite.string.split('/'))
            print cite
    return result
```

Comment: Yes... I think this is what I needed... let me check... Thanks

Comment: For checking `NoneType`, it is preferable to use `is` or `is not` rather than `==` or `!=`

Comment: Yes i am agreeing with that, it was not so pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
    if( (cite.string is None) or (len(cite.string) == 0)):
        continue
    result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0])
```

Comment: I have also error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.. I think I should remove `or (len(cite.string) == 0))`... yes?

Comment: You could remove that. But len check was intentionally made second to None check so that None objects are not checked for len.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded conda and threadpoolctl. It worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).